# Error when writing to log while threading on web requests

Tags: c#, webrequest, parallel.foreach, file-in-use

I am building a program in visual studio 2010 using C# .Net4.0

I have a function that takes in a url and try to get a response. Inside the function, I write to a log file stating successes and errors.

```
public void getResponse(string url, System.IO.StreamWriter writer)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
        writeToLog("Success: " + url, writer);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        writeToLog("Error: " + ex.message, writer);
    }
}
```

I have a list of urls, and I use Parallel.ForEach to run multiple urls at once.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("program.log", true);
string[] urls = {url1, url2, url3, url4, etc}; //have around 30 urls
Parallel.ForEach(urls, url => getResponse(url, writer));
```

When I run the program, sometime I will get an error saying that program.log is being used by another program. This doesn't happen all the time, but once a while it will happen and the program will crash.

**Question:** What should I do to avoid this error? Or, is there an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: StreamWriter is not thread safe. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because StreamWriter isn't thread-safe use a lock statement to lock the writing procedure so the other threads can't enter that line and cause a conflict: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: so if I do it this way it will work?
`Object mylock = new Object();
lock(mylock)
{
    writeToLog("Error: " + ex.message, writer);
}`

Comment: You should only create one lock object, not a new one each time you do a lock. You want using code to be trying to lock on the same thing.

Comment: Like hatchet says, you should create a private field in the class that contains get response. If you do that, it should work. Give it a try and if the problem still happens I'll try and think of something else.

Comment: Okay! I'll try that! Like I said, this problem doesn't happen on every run, so it's probably gonna take me a while before I'm confident to say that fix the problem. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad to see this worked. Never had to use the lock statement myself, but it never hurts to know these things.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't see this error again for a while so I think this actually fix it. Thanks for the help!